# Return [] when scraping data with bs4

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

i am trying to scrape data from a website but so far have been pretty unsuccessful. i tried a couple of ways
most promising has been this. i am trying to get the yearBuild from the site. can someone help me out. any leads would be highly appreciated

```
import bs4 as bs
from selenium import webdriver  
wd = webdriver.Chrome()
url = ("https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/mmsi:255805792")
wd.get(url)
html_source = wd.page_source
wd.quit()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html_source)
elems = soup.select('#yearBuild > b')
print(elems)
print(soup.prettify())
```

here elems is returned as an empty list

Comment: any reason for using selenium?  Selenium is really meant for driving the browser; it's much easier to just pull a page using `requests` if you want to use BS4 on it.

Comment: I think what's happening here is that marinetraffic.com has fairly strict traffic shaping in place.  The first time I ran your code, it worked fine and spit out a fairly big response.  When I tried again using `requests`, I got Access Denied from the server.  You may be encountering the same issue.  I'd add a `print(html_source)` in your code to be sure.

Comment: To give you an idea, lines 2-7 of your script can be done with `import requests; html_source = requests.get("https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/mmsi:255805792").text`

Comment: you need to see what the actual HTML is, so instrument your code with `print(html_source)` and see if you're getting some kind of error message from the site.

Comment: line 2-7 are necessary for preventing access denied. i used selenium to add crfome options which prevent access denied like situations. and even if i did prettify the code, it still returns empty list

Comment: so again, what is the actual HTML you're getting back?

Comment: i am not getting an error while printing the soup.prettify. it renders the site but cant find the data

Comment: That is because #yearBuild element appends later on the page when you scroll down.

Comment: @Dmitry so how do i catch that?

Comment: soup.prettify (html) result -> https://pastebin.com/dv7uJbe9

Comment: You can use something like: `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, x)")` where x - is the hight.

Comment: @Dmitry still empty list

Comment: You should use their API as `Andrej Kesely` provide. This is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use their API to get info about the ship.

For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/mmsi:255805792'

ship_info_url = 'https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/vesselDetails/vesselInfo/shipid:{ship_id}'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
ship_id = re.search(r'shipid:(\d+)', r.url)[1]
data = requests.get(ship_info_url.format(ship_id=ship_id), headers=headers).json()

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
print('Year Built = ', data['yearBuilt'])
```

Prints:

```
{
    "name": "LAILA",
    "nameAis": "LAILA",
    "imo": 9377559,
    "eni": null,
    "mmsi": 255805792,
    "callsign": "CQDP",
    "country": "Portugal",
    "countryCode": "PT",
    "type": "Cargo - Hazard A (Major)",
    "typeSpecific": "Container Ship",
    "typeColor": "7",
    "grossTonnage": 28048,
    "deadweight": 38080,
    "teu": 2700,
    "liquidGas": null,
    "length": 215.5,
    "breadth": 29.87,
    "yearBuilt": 2008,
    "status": "Active",
    "isNavigationalAid": false,
    "correspondingRoamingStationId": null,
    "homePort": null
}
Year Built =  2008
```

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest using VesselFinder instead of MarineTraffic? The data is the same but MarineTraffic is hard to scrape as it's all JavaScript, while VesselFinder can be scraped with just BeautifulSoup.

VesselFinder also uses tables to show the data so it's easy to parse with pandas.

Here's the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels/LAILA-IMO-9377559-MMSI-255805792', headers={'User-Agent': 'iPhone'})

df = pd.read_html(r.text)
ship = ship = pd.concat([df[2], df[3]], ignore_index=True).set_index(0).to_dict()[1]

print(ship['Year of Built'])
```